# How to access the last table using XPath?

Tags: python, xpath

I have an html with 29 tables.

When i do:

```
table = result.xpath(r'//table[last()]')
```

I can't access the table.

But when I do:

```
table = result.xpath(r'//table')
print table[28].attrib
```

I can access the table.

I do not want to pass the table position because this can change, but it will always be the last.

[MY TABLES](https://codeshare.io/adeYpB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python index [-1]

```
result.xpath(r'//table')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether the tables are siblings of each other (they could even be nested!). The expression `//table[last()]` selects every table that is the last table child of its parent. To access the last table child overall, you should use `(//table)[last()]`.